# New Photoshop User - How do I transform an anchor point with pen tool?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm battling with the pen tool at the moment. Probably because I'm using it incorrectly, but anyway. I'm trying to move the top right anchor point of the left shape to meet the edge of the middle shape. Can anyone guide me in the correct direction to fix my issue?[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the Direct Selection Tool (A) to move the anchor points.